# Zoom Website (CSS) that it looks like FHD on bigger screens

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

my Problem is that I have an Website that looks on FHD ( 1920x1080 ) Display like normal and works perfect when scaling down, but on higher resolution the text gets really small and all the css gets really small.

Now I can rewrite the complete css, but that takes too long.

Can I Zoom the page that it looks like FHD on bigger screens (like 4K)?

My meta tag:

```
<meta
    name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
/>
```

FHD:
[image]

4K:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set a max-width on the page content's container so that it does not stretch across the higher resolution, although that will not necessarily do what you want.

You probably need to use media tags to create a breakpoint for the higher resolution, or use relative units for sizing (rem, %).